# Create rect with blurred stroke in svg using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, markup, blurry

How could I create a `rect` with blurred stroke in `svg` using d3.js?

Or at least an ordinary `svg` markup.

I was not able to find such an example or a solution to the problem. If you will tell me that it is a duplicate and provide a similar question I will gladly delete this one. But I am pretty sure that it is not a duplicate.

Comment: set a gaussian blur filter on the stroke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at this article ["Adding a subtle touch of glow to your d3.js visualizations"](https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2016/06/glow-filter-d3-visualization)

If you want to do it manually, you can use the feGaussianBlur filter, more infos here : [feGaussianBlur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur)

From Mozilla Developer :

```html
<svg width="230" height="120"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <filter id="blurMe">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
  </filter>

  <circle cx="60"  cy="60" r="50" fill="green" />

  <circle cx="170" cy="60" r="50" fill="green"
          filter="url(#blurMe)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: But what is wrong with [mine](https://jsfiddle.net/9974hz4u/) implementation? I did just as you did and still was not able to see even a rectangle. Actually what I did following the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feGaussianBlurElement) was: created a blurred version of `GraphicAlpha`, made it `10%` bigger than the original element and then added it and put above it the original element, so I expect to see the shadow on every side equally positioned ( 5% on upper border, on right border, on lower border and on left border).

Comment: Your d3 code doesn't render (even without the filter) - please fix that first

Comment: In your html, your main `<div>` "id" attribute begins with a "#" -- try removing it